# Padding between checkbox and label

Tags: css

For the CSS gurus out there, this markup outputs a checkbox with a label `Value1` to its right, but `Value1` is too close to the checkbox.

```
<dd id="rr-element">
   <label for="rr-1">
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="rr-1" name="rr[]">
      Value 1
   </label>
</dd>
```

So I'm trying to create a `padding-right` effect to the right of the checkbox, but it's not working. The checkbox and label move together. How can I target the checkbox only or its text only so I create a padding gap?

```
dd label input {
   padding-right:100px;
}
```

Comment: Why is your checkbox inside the label?

Comment: @casa: because it avoids having an unclickable gap between label and checkbox.

Comment: @BalusC: Interesting, I never noticed that before.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Use `margin-right`. `padding` is inside the element, and often acts funny with input elements because they are rendered using the OS's native input components, and are a mess to customize in general.

JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/T86h8/)

Comment: Funny I had tried that before posting and it didn't work. Turns out it's a cascading issue, had to add `!important`

Comment: @jblue in that case, I'd rather recommend a `dd#rr-element label input { margin-right:100px; }` - `!important` often creates more problems than it solves

Answer (score 6):

No unclickable gap between checkbox and label.
No line wrap disconnection of the checkbox and label.
No spaces added by code indentations.
More readable.

```
<dd id="rr-element">
   <input type="checkbox" value="1" id="rr-1" name="rr[]">
   <label for="rr-1">Value 1</label>
</dd>
```

```
<style>
#rr-element {
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#rr-element label {
   padding-left: 0.4em;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Utterly redundant `for` attribute, when you *should* put the `checkbox` inside the label.

Comment: Label can enclose the form element.  But it is not as clean.  Both methods are valid.  Both have their pros & cons.  Lets see your checkbox inside label that achieves all the things I listed.

Comment: @Dark Absol - Redundant != bad.  "Even in such cases however, it is considered best practice to set the for attribute because some assistive technologies do not understand implicit relationships between labels and widgets."  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/How_to_structure_an_HTML_form

Comment: Pretty sure I'd consider that a fault in the assistive technology and recommend the use of non-faulty technology -shrug-