# Extra space between label and checkbox in Firefox

Tags: html, css, checkbox, cross-browser

I have a list of checkboxes with labels and I am noticing that the spacing looks different in Firefox in comparison to IE.

I have applied the CSS below to try and remove all spacing.

```
border: 0 none;
margin: 0;
outline: medium none;
padding: 0;
```

Unfortunately, as you can see from the screen shots below, there still seems to be some extra space between the Firefox checkbox and label.

Firefox: [image]

Internet Explorer [image]

Why does Firefox still show space between the checkbox and label but Internet Explorer has none using the same CSS?

Comment: it depends up on the browser, If you need same element then better use custom checkbox.

Comment: Try this for firefox : `input[type="checkbox"] {-moz-appearance: none;}`

Comment: Might be worth a read - http://robobruin.blogspot.co.uk/2007/09/fixing-ie-checkbox-paddingmargin.html

Comment: check this out also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877460/padding-between-checkbox-and-label

Comment: @Brewal - i am not so concerned with the checkbox appearence . .more concerned with spacing between checkbo and text

Comment: Sorry. I tried a fiddle under firefox and I don't have any space. Could you try making one to see if I has something to do with the html ?

Comment: every browser renders this differently. If you want to have concise behaviour, you should explicitely set margin right on the checkbox. Also please add your html markup for the input-label.

Comment: because chrome is the best?

Comment: You could use a styled checkbox so that you have more control over it.  [This may help](http://csscheckbox.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, the reason as to why you're seeing this is that such details aren't defined as a standard anywhere, and come down to the 'user-agent stylesheet' - a set of default styles that are applied by the specific browser.

It's something that frustrates plenty of designers/developers, and has led to the development of some kinds of CSS Reset stylesheets. One of the best (in my opinion) is [`normalize.css`](http://nicolasgallagher.com/about-normalize-css/), which aims to provide consistent and sensible defaults, smoothing over cross-browser inconsistencies like the one you've described.

Comment: There's also a thing called [Formalize CSS](http://formalize.me/) that attempts to provide those consistent defaults specifically for forms. There are some differences between it and normalize, as formalize goes a bit further, and one could (I imagine) use both on the same project. Many designers hold off on using formalize, as it can be argued that it gets rid of user expectations based on what the browser normally does.

Comment: Hadn't heard of it before. Thanks for the info, I'll look in to it.